# Finding indefinite integral $\int\frac{\sqrt{a+x}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x}}\, dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{a+x}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x}}\, dx$$

A few days ago I asked a similar (looking) question where all the pluses here were minuses.
It could be much more easily manipulated than this one using difference of $2$ squares. The other method used to solve the previous problem is replacing $x$ with $\arccos^2x$. Out of curiosity I have attempted to use the latter method to solve this integral, and made a little progress with it.

Just to make sure this integral has a solution, Wolframalpha found a [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28a%2Bx%29%2F%28sqrt%28a%29%2Bsqrt%28x%29%29) that was not too bad.

Replacing $x$ with $\arctan^2t$, the integral becomes

$$\int\frac{2a \sec^3 t \tan t}{1+\tan t}\, dt$$

From here I tried to perfrom integration by parts, where $2a$ is taken outside of the integral, and numberator split into $sec x\tan x$ times $\sec^2x$, as $u$ and $v'$ respectively. $v$ can easily be found but $u'$ is messy. Integration by parts needed to be done again, also, which would have ended up really messy.

So I tried to convert everything into sines and cosines, then letting $u$ equal $\cos t$, and $du$ equal to $-\sin tdt$.

$$\int\frac{2a\sin t}{\cos^3 t \cos t +\sin t}\, dt$$

$$\int\frac{-2au}{u^3 u+\sqrt{1-u^2}}\, dt$$

However that doesn't look very pretty either. I don't think it is possible to perform Partial Fraction Decomposition on it.

What are the right paths to take to solve this integral? Are there any 'tricks of the trade' I have missed along the way?

Comment: This was solve here before and not by that hideous trigonometric substitution.

Comment: I think you're misusing backslash.

Comment: I do not know where the $\tan t$ on top comes from. If you really want to imitate the trigonometric substitution (which is not necessarily a good idea) then $x=a\sinh^2 t$ looks better.

Comment: Kaster: please give advice; i'm new. RGB: can you send me the link to the solution or what was 'solved here before'? thanks

Comment: If you asked it, it is in your profile. (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443824/finding-indefinite-integral)

Comment: Do notice RGB that question has subtle differences with this one! It's 2 minuses compared to 2 pluses here! Difference of 2 squares can't be used as easily here as it can be there. Thanks for information on Euler substitution though.

Comment: Substituting $x=az$ you obtain
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{a+x}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x}}\, dx=a\int\frac{\sqrt{1+z}}{1+\sqrt{z}}\, dz.
$$
Now using Wolframalpha step-by-step solution or Maple (Tools->Tutors->Calculus Single Variable->Integration methods) you can follow the calculations. The main tricks are trigonometric,hyperbolic substitutions, partial fraction decomposition. And a lot of tedious calculations.

Comment: @vesszabo: can you send a link to one of these solutions? I have tried to get a wolfram alpha step be step solution, and have signed up, but it says it is not available. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

We multiply by $1 = \frac{\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{x}}$:
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{a+x}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x}}dx = \int\frac{\sqrt{a^2+ax} - \sqrt{ax + x^2}}{a - x}dx$$
Now we can separate the integral into two parts. For the left part:
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{a^2+ax}}{a - x}dx = \int\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2a^2-y}dy = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{a}\int\frac{z^2}{a\sqrt{2}+z}+\frac{z^2}{a\sqrt{2}-z}dz$$
After substitutions $y = a^2 + ax$ and $z^2 = y$. This integral evaluates easily to
$$4z-8+2\sqrt{2}a(\log(z+a\sqrt{2}) - \log(z-a\sqrt{2})) =$$
$$=4\sqrt{a^2+ax}-8+2\sqrt{2}a(\log(\sqrt{a^2+ax}+a\sqrt{2}) - \log(\sqrt{a^2+ax}-a\sqrt{2}))$$
I haven't tried yet to evaluate the other integral.

Comment: you made the mistake $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x})\neq a+x$

Comment: @Norbert Oh, hell! You're right of course.

Comment: This half worked out quite neatly. The other half looks much nastier. Any ideas as to nudge out the other half? I don't think a similar substitution would work. Your method seems to be the neatest so far!

Comment: @YunFeiOuYang Thanks :) For the second part, I have tried various techniques, but got nowhere. The best I have it the substitution $y = x+a$, which gives $\int \frac{\sqrt{ax + x^2}}{a-x}dx = \int \sqrt{1-\frac{a}{y}}dy$, but then I don't know how to go on.

Comment: @Daniel: Your solution looks a little like the answer by Wolframalpha, especially the part of 2sqrt(2)a. (see #solution in original question). It is really surprising how something so ordinary looking can be so hard! :)

Answer (score 5):

One way to approach this problem is to use the following substitutions:

$b^2=a$ and $x=b^2u^2$ and $u=\frac{2v}{1-v^2}\implies\sqrt{1+u^2}=\frac{1+v^2}{1-v^2}\text{ and }\mathrm{d}u=2\frac{1+v^2}{(1-v^2)^2}\mathrm{d}v$

For example
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\sqrt{a+x}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\frac{\sqrt{b^2+b^2u^2}}{b+bu}2b^2u\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=2b^2\int\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{1+u}u\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=8b^2\int\frac{v(1+v^2)^2}{(1+2v-v^2)(1-v^2)^3}\,\mathrm{d}v
\end{align}
$$
Now, at least, the problem can be handled with partial fractions.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{8v(1+v^2)^2}{(1+2v-v^2)(1-v^2)^3}
&=\frac2{(v+1)^3}+\frac1{(v+1)^2}+\frac3{(v+1)}\\
&-\frac2{(v-1)^3}-\frac3{(v-1)^2}-\frac3{(v-1)}\\
&+\frac{2\sqrt2}{(v-1-\sqrt2)}-\frac{2\sqrt2}{(v-1+\sqrt2)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This method yields ok results. Partial fraction decomposition : http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=ec4a062bb304f88c2ba0b631d7acabbc

Comment: It will take long time to handle the partial fractions.

Comment: Substitution back will be a problem because v can only be expressed as two quadratic roots of u. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=az$ and $z=s^2$, where $s\geq 0$. Then

\begin{aligned}
\int\frac{\sqrt{a+x}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x}}\, dx &=a \int\frac{\sqrt{1+z}}{1+\sqrt{z}}\, dz \\
&=2a \int \sqrt{1+s^2}\frac{s}{1+s}\, ds \\
&=2a \int \sqrt{1+s^2}\,ds-2a \int \frac{\sqrt{1+s^2}}{1+s}\, ds \\
&=2aI_1-2aI_2.
\end{aligned}

Here (using the standard substitution $s=\sinh(t)$) 
$$
I_1=\frac{1}{2}s\sqrt{1+s^2}+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{arcsinh}(s)+C.
$$
Now consider $I_2$.

In the integrand $\sqrt{1+s^2}/(1+s)$, substitute $s=\tan(u),\,(0\leq u<\pi/2)$ and  $ds=du \sec^2(u)$. Then $\sqrt{1+s^2}=\sqrt{1+\tan^2(u)}=\sec(u)$ and $u=\tan^{-1}(s)$,
$$
I_2=\int\frac{\sec^3(u)}{1+\tan(u)}\,du.
$$
In the integrand $\sec^3(u)/(1+\tan(u))$, substitute (the standard)  $p=\tan(u/2),\,(0\leq p<1)$ and  $dp=(1/2)du\sec^2(u/2)$. Then 
 using this substitution $\sin(u)=(2 p)/(1+p^2)$, $\cos(u)=(1-p^2)/(1+p^2)$ and  $du=(2  dp)/(1+p^2)$ we obtain
$$
I_2=\int 2 \frac{(1+p^2)^2}{(1-p^2)^3 (1+\frac{2 p}{1-p^2})} dp=\int-\frac{2(1+p^2)^2}{(-1+p^2-2p)(-1+p^2)^2}\,dp.
$$
Here (using computer)
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\frac{2(1+p^2)^2}{(-1+p^2-2p)(-1+p^2)^2} &=\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}-\frac{4}{-1+p^2-2p} \\
&=-\frac{1}{p+1}+\frac{1}{p-1}-\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
These 5 integrals can be calculated easily. Now you should make back substitutions and applying a lot of trigonometric identities to obtain the final answer. I omit the details because you asked about methods ('tricks') of calculating integrals.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid trigonometric substitutions, they only work in specially designed examples, i.e. if it is your only tool you will easy find exercises in which they are a pain.
2. Rationalize the denominator, by using difference of squares as you have seen before.
3. Rewrite as a sum of integrals of the form $\int R(\sqrt{\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}})\text{d}x$, where $R$ are rational functions.
4. Apply the substitution $y=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, which always work for all of these.

**Addendum:** For that integral that you got at the end you can use [Euler's substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). This turns that last integrand into a rational function and from there partial fraction decomposition finishes it. Still, the trigonometric substitution was a long path to get to the rational function.

Answer (score 0):

With $x=a \sinh^2 t$
\begin{align}
&\frac1a\int\frac{\sqrt{a+x}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x}}\, dx
= 2\int \frac {\sinh t \cosh^2 t}{1+\sinh t}dt\\
= &\ 2\int \cosh^2t-\sinh t+1-\frac2{1+\sinh t}\ dt\\
=&\ \frac12\sinh2t -2\cosh t+3t
-2\sqrt2 \tanh^{-1}\frac{\sinh t-1}{\sqrt2\cosh t}\\
=&\ \sqrt{\frac xa +1}\left(\sqrt{\frac xa} -2\right)
 +3\sinh^{-1}\sqrt {\frac xa}
-2\sqrt2 \tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt a}{\sqrt2\sqrt{x+a}}
\end{align}